# Query string into array then parsed into a string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, cookies, query-string

My goal is to create a form that takes user information, then add it to the url query string. The query string information will be pulled back down into an array then displayed on the second page as text. I am stuck on the last part, taking the array and placing it within a paragraph element as text. Somewhere between taking the query data from the array, the problem happens.

I've tried converting it toString(); inserting the javascript into span elements. Within the browser inspector, my array values do exist.

HTML Page 1

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Test Site</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test Site</h1>

      <form action="thankyou.htm" autocomplete="on">
         <fieldset class="text" id="fs1">
            <label for="name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" />
            <label for="name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" />
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset class="btn">
            <input type="submit" id="nextBtn" value="Next &gt;" />
         </fieldset>
      </form>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML Page 2

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Test Site</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Thank You</h1>

  <p> Hello <span id="newtext"></span> it is nice to meet you</p>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
var queryArray = [];

//FUNCTIONS
function addQuery(){
    //Concatenate values to query string
var savedData = "?fname=" +
    document.getElementById("fName").value;
savedData += "&lname" +
    document.getElementById("lName").value;
savedData += "&email" +
    document.getElementById("email").value;
savedData += "&phone" +
    document.getElementById("phone").value;

location.href = "index.htm" + savedData;
}

function populateInfo(){
    if(location.search){
        var queryData = location.search;
        queryData = queryData.substring(1, queryData.length);
        queryArray = queryData.split("&");
    }
}

var yourname = queryArray;
document.getElementById("newtext").innerHTML = yourname;


//EVENT LISTENERS

 //adds Query only upon submit else causes refresh error
  if(window.addEventListener){
     window.addEventListener("submit", addQuery, false);
 } else if(window.attachEvent){
     window.attachEvent("onsubmit", addQuery);
 }

 //adds query string into array for more uses
 if (window.addEventListener){
     window.addEventListener("load", populateInfo, false);
 }else if (window.attachEvent) {
     window.attachEvent("onload", populateInfo);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform the URL arguments to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with this ES6 script:

```
var mp = new Map(queryData.split("&").map( s => s.split('=') ));
document.getElementById('newtext').textContent = mp.get('fname') + ' ' + mp.get('lname');
```

In ES5 you could use a plain object instead of a Map:

```
var mp = queryData.split("&").reduce(function(o, s) {
    var p = s.split('=');
    o[p[0]] = p[1];
    return o;
}, {});
document.getElementById('newtext').textContent = mp['fname'] + ' ' + mp['lname'];
```

Comment: Thank you for replying back to me. I didn't know of the Map object until you took time to answer my post. I'm still trying to get this to work but you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Update. I got it to work. I made the variable mp a global variable, added a return within the function and changed checked my calls again. Thank you again